# Getting 401 Unauthorized Error when pulling Authentication Methods

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am quite new in Microsoft Graph API and we have requirements to pull Authentication methods of the users who signed-in thru Azure AD B2C policy.

The user authenticated after login, however, when calling the code below from the application encountered a "401 - Unauthorized" and shows "The user is unauthenticated".

**Graph API**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/authentication/methods/
```

**Error in the App:**

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error Calling the Graph API:
{
"error": {
"code": "unauthenticated",
"message": "The user is unauthenticated.",
"innerError": {
"message": "The user is unauthenticated.",
"date": "2020-07-09T11:07:29",
"request-id": "bea50bdf-28f6-4a67-a5a4-3aacd8f23251"
}
}
})
```

I also provided the proper API permission in App Registration in Azure.

```
Type: Delegated
Permission: UserAuthenticationMethod.Read, UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All
```

I came across in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-methods?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) where **"Application" is not yer supported.**

Screenshot:
[Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9mdg.png)

**Question:**

May I know if this is the reason why I encountered "401 - Authorized" and shows the "The user is unauthenticated" errors since pulling Authentication Methods from Application is not yet supported ?
Or probably there are missing permission that I have not yet considered.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Daemon application, then the 401 status code Authentication error here is mainly due to the application permissions which are not supported and refer this [similar issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7999), even if you specify delegated permissions, since there wouldn't be any user to login in a daemon scenario you will face this issue. If you use the delegated permissions scenario then you would be getting those details as shown below.

[image]

Here the Graph explorer acts as an application and the user logs in and set required permission and roles and call the endpoint, it succeeds as shown above.

The required permissions for doing these operations are shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-methods?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions).

If you want to check other users authentication methods you need to have one of these roles.

- Global admin
- Global reader
- Privileged authentication admin
- Authentication admin (only sees masked phone numbers)

Comment: Thanks for the response Shiva. Since our application allow the user to sign-in and by design let the application get the Authentication methods(given the permission mentioned has been granted to the user), it is not considered a Daemon app, right? I also have tried querying directly in the Graph Explorer you mentioned with the proper permission and was able to get the results. If that same user logs in to our app, the app can also get it? I will try this one though. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, If the same user logs in having these proper permissions then it should succeed. And yes the Graph Explorer acts as an application in your tenant after you login. You can search for Graph Explorer in your Enterprise Applications :)