# Azure B2C Works On My Local Machine But Not On Azure

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I have created a Blazor application that calls a Web API(.Net) and uses Azure AD B2C for authentication. This works fine on my local machine. I can authenticate via the login screen and call the relevant endpoint. Once I deploy the application to Azure I get this error on the browser:
***info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)***

On the Blazor(UI) side I have this set up:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://CarehomeRoomBookingTest.b2clogin.com/CarehomeRoomBookingTest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpIn",
    "ClientId": "77##############################",
    "ClientSecret": "99#########################",
    "ValidateAuthority": false
  }
```

On the Web API side I have this set up:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://CarehomeRoomBookingTest.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "16#############################",
    "Domain": "CarehomeRoomBookingTest.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi_reset_v2",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpIn",
    "TenantId": "38#############################"
  }
```

Why would this be happening when the application is deployed and hosted on Azure?

Comment: Have you configured the callback url for Azure in the portal?

Comment: The callback works fine. It works fine locally i.e it goes off to B2C gets the token and I can then use that token to call my API. The callback works fine via Azure as well, it gets the token but then it fails when I call the protected API endpoint.

Comment: @Mathew Watts, is the api and client on the same base address?

Comment: @Xserge No, different addresses. The UI is on a static web app so Microsoft generate a random url.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any of below is your case:

1.See if  scope for your API  that Your front-end app needs to use is correct. This way it  will get an access token which is meant for your API. Register a
scope for your API app registration through the Expose an API
section and use the scope in your front-end app.

[image]

and grant admin consent :

[image]

Your scopes will be present this way
[image]

Please make sure to include the scopes exposed in the portal for your backend api in the auth in your code

2. Also please check if you have given proper permissons or if use of
   delegated permissions  is the issue .See
   [getting-401-unauthorized-error-StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814335/getting-401-unauthorized-error-when-pulling-authentication-methods)

Comment: Your comment "Please make sure to include the scopes exposed in the portal for your backend api in the auth in your code" can you provide some more detail of what you mean please?

Comment: @MatthewWatts, when requesting for a token from AAD B2C, that makes a call to an API, you have to request the scope. e.g "offline_access". If this still gives your problems reached out to me on github. I would love to help you work this out plus I have a bit of time to worst 2 days from the date of this writing. GitHub profile:  serge-n

Comment: I still cant get this to work. Below is the generated token. It seems correct, I noticed was that the iss has V2.0 but I do not use this in my API anywhere. Does that make a difference? {
  "exp": 1657142857,
  "nbf": 1657139257,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "https://carehomeroombookingtest.b2clogin.com/38###############/v2.0/",
  "sub": "444##############################",
  "aud": "77######################",
  "nonce": "defaultNonce",
  "iat": 1657139257,
  "auth_time": 1657139257,
  "given_name": "Matthew",
  "family_name": "Watts",
  "name": "Matt",
  "tfp": "B2C_1_SignUpIn"
}

Comment: @Xserge The offline access is set for API Graph. I am not using it for my scope, not sure where I would add that. Is there a way I can message you on GitHub?

Comment: @MatthewWatt Yes. GitHub. Even graph APIs need a permitted scope.

Comment: @Xserge This is the scope I have set up and use on the client application  : 
Api.ReadWrite
Delegated
Get Full Access
Yes
 Granted for CarehomeRoomBookingTest